# Construction of random variables with symmetric matrices

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $H,K \in S_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $KH=HK$, $R \in S_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Tr(R)=1$. Prove that there exist two random variables $X,Y$ such that for all $s,t$ reals , we have :
$$E(e^{i(tX+sY}))=Tr(R \cdot e^{i(tH+sK)}).$$
Denote by $f(s,t)$ this function.
Let $l_1,\dots,l_n$ be complex numbers, $s_1,\dots,s_n,t_1,\dots,t_n$ be real numbers. Prove that:
$$\sum_{ 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n } l_i\bar{l_j} f(s_i-s_j,t_i-t_j) \geq 0$$

The second question is easy: we get $E(|z|^2) \geq 0 $.  I have no clue how to do the first question, any ideas? Is it something well known in random matrices theory? (I am not familiar with this field.)
Note that $S_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of matrices with eignvalues $\geq 0$.

Comment: Are you sure about the $l_i$ real and the $s_i. t_j$ complex?

Comment: sorry , corrected ! Yes we can suppose that $H,K$ are diagonal (spectral theorem ...) but i still cannot construct $X,Y$

Comment: I assume that $S_n$ means symmetric matrices.  And in the second displayed equation, did you really mean for $i \le j$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ and $K$ commute, there is an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that both $\bar H = QHQ'$ and $\bar K =QKQ'$ are diagonal; let $\bar R=QRQ'$.
Since $H$ and $K$ commute, $\exp(itH+isK)=\exp(itH)\exp(isK)$ and $$\begin{align*}f(s,t)&=\operatorname{Tr}\left(\vphantom{\bar R}R\exp(itH)\exp(isK)\right)\\&=\operatorname{Tr}\left(\bar R\exp(it\bar H)\exp(is\bar K)\right)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n \bar R_k e^{it\bar H_k}e^{is\bar K_k},\end{align*}$$
where $\bar R_k, \bar H_k$,  and $\bar K_k$,  denote the diagonal entries in $\bar R, \bar H$, and $ \bar K$, respectively. Note that $\operatorname{Tr}(\bar R)=\operatorname{Tr}(R)=1$, so the numbers $\bar R_k$  add to $1$ and thus specify a probability distribution. (The eigenvalues of $R$ are non-negative, so $\bar R$ is psd, and hence has non-negative diagonal entries $\bar R_k$.)

If you let the random variables $(X,Y)$ take on the values $(\bar H_k,\bar K_k)$ with probability $\bar R_k$, we see that $f$ is the characteristic function (I mean, the probabalists' characteristic function) of $(X,Y)$, as desired.